# Angular - Failed to load resource: Preflight response was not successful

Tags: angular, browser, get, console, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to hit an API endpoint from Angular to get back JSON data. My code is below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-api-caller',
  templateUrl: './api-caller.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./api-caller.component.css']
})

export class ApiCallerComponent implements OnInit {

    // works with 'https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler'

  ngOnInit(): void {

    const options = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json') };
    this.http.get('https://api.upsie.com/api/helloworld', options).subscribe(
      data => {
      console.log(data);
    },
      err => {
      console.log('An Error occured');
      });
  }

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

}
```

The browser console shows an error:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3gEh.png)

What does "Failed to load resource: Preflight response was not successful" mean and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Angular sends an OPTIONS request before the actual request. Therefore your API has to allow the correct CORS headers to support the OPTIONS preflight.

If you use express take a look at the [cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) package.